# Function being triggered on Input entry, need to be triggered when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

I have a form that has three input fields, an Update button, and a Cancel button.  I'm currently working on disabling the Update button if any of the three fields are empty, and then re-enabling the button once all the fields are populated.  The input fields and the form buttons are kept in separate components, so I've been pulling the Input field values into the proper component using DOM manipulation.

I have a function written using lodash's find method that should do the trick, but for some reason it is being triggered when a change has been made to an input field, and not when the page loads.  Additionally, it pulls in the previous value of the Input field instead of the actual value shown when the page loads.

For example, if the page loads with no value in one of the input fields, the Update button will be enabled.  Once you type the first character into the empty input field, for example the letter A, the button will be disabled and the function will read the field's value as being empty.  If I then type the letter S into the field, so its actual value is AS, the button will then be re-enabled and the function will read the value as A, its previous value.

Since the function returns a boolean value, I am calling it when I pass the disabled prop to the button.  Below is the function I've got written, as well as how the function is being called within the Render function.  I feel like there is something obvious that I'm missing, and if anyone can provide assistance on thiis I'd greatly appreciiate it.  Please let me know if there's more information needed from me.

Disabled Button Check:

```
  disableButtonCheck = () => {
    const dataField = document.getElementsByClassName('InputField__input___i2o8Y');

    const nullValueChecker = find(dataField, (field) => {
      return field.defaultValue === '';
    });

    if (nullValueChecker) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Disable Button in Render:

```
  <div className={style['action-buttons']}>
    <PrimaryButton
      onClick={() => {
        this.updateHandler();
      }}
      disabled={this.disableButtonCheck()}              
      extraClassName={style.update}
      data-action="update"
    >
```

Update:  I should have noted that I'm calling the input fields as a class, they're being called as an array of objects.  I'm trying to iterate through the array and return only a true value if any empty strings are found, otherwise return false if there aren't.

Comment: So your main goal is to enable the update button only when the input fields have some values in it right ?

Comment: Right, only when ALL of the fields have a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this issue isn't related to when the function itself is being triggered.  The issue is the DOM elements being set to my variable within the function when a user types into a field, not when the function is actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.updateButton').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#inputFeild').keyup(function(){
        $('.updateButton').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
    })
});
```

initially you disable the button, on every keystroke check if the user has input anything, then enable the update button if required.

Comment: I like the looks of this, will try when I get back to my computer and will update.  Thanks!

Comment: The input fields have no ID assigned and share a class name, so that's how I'd need to pull it.  When I pull the class, it creates an array of objects, each object has a property containing the listed value.  With that being the case, would I need to use a filter method on the returned array?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using react, I'd recommend keeping the disabled boolean in state. You could achieve what you want with something like this:

State:

```
state = {
  disabledSubmit: true
}
```

Form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitFunc}>

    <input className="form-input" type="text" onChange={this.checkValue}/>
    <input className="form-input" type="text" onChange={this.checkValue}/>
    <input className="form-input" type="text" onChange={this.checkValue}/>
    <input className="form-input" type="text" onChange={this.checkValue}/>

    <input class="form-submit" type="submit" disabled={this.state.disabledSubmit}/>

</form>
```

Function:

```
checkValue = () => {
   var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-input')
   var arr = []
   for (var i =0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      inputs[i].value === '' ? arr.push(inputs[i].value) : null
   }
   arr.length > 0 ? this.setState({disabledSubmit: true}) : this.setState({disabledSubmit: false})
}
```

Unfortunately you can't use functions like filter or map when dealing with an array of HTML elements so you need to use a for loop.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Originally I said that you could use collect all the inputs during `componentDidMount` and store in state so you wouldn't have to do `document.getElementsByClassName` every time someone types something in. If you kept the elements in state you'd have to update the elements in an onChange anyway to keep track of changes and update them in state. So this is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

I have to preface this answer with the fact that the React way would be to attach `onChange` props to the inputs directly and update the component state accordingly.

If for whatever reason you don't have access to the `input` elements, an alternative would be to use the `componentDidMount` and attach event handlers to the `oninput` or `onchange` events:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.oninput = this.handleInput;
    // use onchange to only call the handler when the input is blurred (focus transitions out of the input)
  });
}

handleInput = e => {
  const inputName = e.target.name;
  if (e.target.value) {
    // The input has some input, so set it's state to true
    this.setState({ [inputName]: true, message: "" });
  } else if (this.state[inputName]) {
    // The input no longer has any input, so set it's state to false
    this.setState({ [inputName]: false, message: "" });
  }
};

render() {
  // This boolean will be reevaluated on each render which is called after each setState.
  const isButtonActive =
    this.state["input-1"] && this.state["input-2"] && this.state["input-3"];
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <Input name="input-1" />
      <Input name="input-2" />
      <Input name="input-3" />
      <button disabled={!isButtonActive}>Submit</button>
      <div>{this.state.message}</div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

To see the working example, check out this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5koq5nv32l